# How do I write a new Linux driver for an i2c device?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, i2c

I have a usb device with some i2c control functions and I would like to add a userspace API for twiddling those bits. How do I add i2c support to my device's existing driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The excellent [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) book covers a lot of what it takes to write a Linux device driver, including USB specifics (see chapter 13).